# hello I am new I am lost with this problem object has no attribute 'get ,someone who can guide me?

Tags: python, class, object, get, syntax-error

I'm looking for a solution to this error in Django. I sent you my forms and my view, and the error is as follows in my app . According to what appears to me in the tracer back, I would mark an error in the views line if `form.is_valid()` I already looked at a lot of things, but the truth is I'm already lost. I need help with the damn error.

The `CargaForm` object has no attribute 'get

Traceback
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tienda/cargar/

```
   Django Version: 3.2.13
   Python Version: 3.10.6
   Installed Applications:
   ['django.contrib.sites',
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'captcha',
   'productos.apps.ProductosConfig',
   'web.apps.WebConfig',
   'contacto.apps.ContactoConfig',
   'tienda.apps.TiendaConfig',
    'debug_toolbar']
    Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, 
     in inner
      response = get_response(request)
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in 
      _get_response
       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\Proyectos\cerverzeria\cerverzeria\tienda\views.py", line 13, in 
       cargar_imagen
        if form.is_valid():
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in is_valid
       return self.is_bound and not self.errors
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 170, in errors
       self.full_clean()
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 372, in full_clean
         self._clean_fields()
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 384, in 
       _clean_fields
        value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
 File "C:\Users\PY310\diplo\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 263, in 
         value_from_datadict
         return data.get(name)

        Exception Type: AttributeError at /tienda/cargar/
        Exception Value: 'CargaForm' object has no attribute 'get'


Forms------------------------------
from django.forms import ModelForm
from productos.models import Producto

class CargaForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model= Producto
        fields = ['Producto', 'Marca', 'fecha_publicacion', 'imagen']

def __init__(self, *args, **Kwargs): 
    super(CargaForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **Kwargs) 


 Views--------------------------------
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.shortcuts import redirect
 from tienda.forms import CargaForm
 from productos.models import Producto 

def cargar_imagen(request):
params={}

if request.method =='POST':
    form = CargaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    params['form'] = form

    if form.is_valid():
        producto = form.cleaned_data['producto']
        fecha_publicacion = form.cleaned_data['fecha_publicacion']
        imagen = form.cleaned_data['imagen']

        nuevo_producto = Producto(producto=producto, fecha_publicacion=fecha_publicacion, imagen=imagen)
        nuevo_producto.save()
        return redirect('index')

else:  
    form= CargaForm()
    params['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'tienda/formulario.html', params)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would suggest you to edit title of your question to make it better and understandable for users, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in the file 'widgets.py',and i suggest you should change like this.
change

> return data.get(name)

into:

> return data.POST.get(name)